# PHP require no trae los scripts correctamente, las funciones no corren

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Me di cuenta que los scripts contenidos en scripts.php no corren dentro del archivo scripts.php, es un codigo ya muy viejo y no actualizado.

Esto es lo que tengo en index.php, lo importante se encuentra en "Registro" y "Login", pero no funcionan correctamente los botones para hacer el registro ni el de iniciar sesion.

```
    <?php require("complementos/user_language.php"); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="<?php echo $user_language; ?>">
        <head>
            <title>Evolution Group</title>
            <link href="images/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
            <!-- Metas -->
            <?php require("complementos/metas.php"); ?>
            <!-- Metas -->
        </head>
        <body>   
            <div class="BVedeLogo">
              <img src="images/logo.svg" height="50" style="padding: 5px;">
            </div>    
            <!-- Contenido -->
            <div class="reto_contenido_index" id="inicio_session">
                <div class="reto_logo">
                    <img src="images/reto_1.png" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <form id="formLoginReto" style="text-align: center;">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email"  name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $inicio_sesion_formulario[0]; ?>">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $inicio_sesion_formulario[1]; ?>">
                      </div>
                    </form>      
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-full" onclick="login_reto();"><?php echo $btnOpciones[1]; ?></button><br>
                    <div style="text-align: center; padding: 10px;">
                      <a href="recovery.php" target="new" style="color: #fff;">
                        <?php echo $btnNuevo[0]; ?>
                      </a><br>
                      <a href=# style="color: #fff;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modales_comentarios">Envíanos tus comentarios</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="linea"><?php echo $linea[0]; ?></div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-full" onclick="verOcultar(0);"><?php echo $btnOpciones[0]; ?></button><br><br>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-full" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MensajeUModal"><?php echo $btnOpciones[2]; ?></button>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px;"><?php echo $mensajes_del_universo[0]; ?></p>           
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="reto_contenido_index_2" id="registro">    
                <div class="reto_logo">
                    <img src="images/reto_1.png" width="100%">
                </div>        
                <div>
                    <form id="formRegistro">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="registro_nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[0]; ?>">
                      </div>                 
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="registro_apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[1]; ?>">
                      </div>                 
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="registro_telefono" name="registro_telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[2]; ?>">
                      </div> 
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="registro_email" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[3]; ?>">
                      </div>                      
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="registro_username" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[4]; ?>">
                      </div>                                                      
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="registro_password" placeholder="<?php echo $registo_form[5]; ?>">
                        <span class="label label-default" id="registro_password_label"></span>
                      </div>   
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control b-dropdown" id="registro_pais" name="registro_pais">
                          <option selected style="display: none;" value="null"><?php echo $registo_form[11]; ?></option>                      
                        </select>  
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control b-dropdown" id="registro_centro" name="registro_centro">
                          <option selected style="display: none;" value="null"><?php echo $registo_form[12]; ?></option>                      
                        </select>  
                      </div>                
                    </form>      
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-full" onclick="registros();"><?php echo $btnOpciones[0]; ?></button>              
                    <div class="linea"><?php echo $linea[0]; ?></div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-full" onclick="verOcultar(1);"><?php echo $btnOpciones[1]; ?></button>                      
                </div>
            </div>        
            <!-- Contenido -->

            <!-- Mensajes -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="MensajeUModal" style="background: url("/images/azul.jpg") center center fixed;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
              <div class="animated fadeIn dzjRvv"></div>
              <div class="hover">
                <div class="btnCloseHover" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="tUniverso animated zoomIn"></div>
                <div class="tUniversoM animated flipInX">
                  <div class="mensajeU"></div>
                </div>
              </div>       
            </div>
            <!-- Mensajes -->

            <!-- Modales -->
            <?php require("complementos/modales.php"); ?>
            <!-- Modales -->
            <!-- Links -->
            <?php require("complementos/links.php"); ?>
            <!-- Links -->
            <!-- Scripts -->
            <?php require("complementos/scripts.php"); ?>
            <!-- Scripts -->
        </body>
    </html>
```

Scripts.php esta en esa ruta llamada complementos/scripts.php como pueden ver, la funcion de traer el modal para enviar comentarios si funciona pero no funciona la de ocultar el registro la cual tuve que separar. El código no ha sido actualizado desde el 2016 y por lo que veo usa métodos de PHP 4

Este el contenido que quiero corregir scripts.php. Estoy intentando corregir un error que no permite registrar usuarios

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var formRegistro = $("#formRegistro");
    var formLoginReto = $("#formLoginReto");
    var formRecovery = $("#formRecovery");
    var formUpdate = $("#formUpdate");
    var formMensaje = $("#formMensaje");
    var addPaises;
    var addCentros;
    var registroMail;
    var centro;
    var registro_puntos;
    var fechaRetos;
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        jQuery('#registro_telefono').keypress(function(tecla) {
            if(tecla.charCode < 48 || tecla.charCode > 57) return false;
        }); 

        jQuery('#comodin_telefono').keypress(function(tecla) {
            if(tecla.charCode < 48 || tecla.charCode > 57) return false;
        });             

        $("html").niceScroll({
            scrollspeed: 100,
            mousescrollstep: 38,
            cursorwidth: 10,
            cursorborder: 0,
            cursorcolor: '#693',
            autohidemode: true,
            zindex: 999999999,
            horizrailenabled: false,
            cursorborderradius: 0,
        });

        formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_password']").keyup(function(e){
             var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$", "g");
             var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{7,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))).*$", "g");
             var enoughRegex = new RegExp("(?=.{6,}).*", "g");
             if(strongRegex.test($(this).val())) {
                $("#registro_password_label").removeClass('label-default label-primary label-success label-info label-warning label-danger');
                $("#registro_password_label").addClass('label-success');
                $("#registro_password_label").html('<i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>'); 
             }else if(mediumRegex.test($(this).val())) {
                $("#registro_password_label").removeClass('label-default label-primary label-success label-info label-warning label-danger');
                $("#registro_password_label").addClass('label-warning');
                $("#registro_password_label").html('<i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>'); 
             }else{
                $("#registro_password_label").removeClass('label-default label-primary label-success label-info label-warning label-danger');
                $("#registro_password_label").addClass('label-danger');
                $("#registro_password_label").html('<i class="fa fa-star"></i>'); 
             }
             return true;
        });     

        cargar_paises();

        $("#registro_pais").on("change", function(){
            var datos = $("#registro_pais").val();
            cargar_centros(datos);
        }); 

        $('#MensajeUModal').on('show.bs.modal.bs.modal', function (e) {
          mensaje_universo();
        });

        $('#modales_mensajesw').on('hide.bs.modal.bs.modal', function (e) {
            window.close(); 
        });     



        $(".btnInstrucciones").on("click", function(e){
            $("#dashboardPT").fadeOut();
            $("#instruccionesPT").fadeIn();
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
        });
        $(".btnCatalogo").on("click", function(e){
            $("#dashboardPT").fadeOut();
            $("#catalogoPT").fadeIn();
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
        });
        $(".btnHistorial").on("click", function(e){
            $("#dashboardPT").fadeOut();
            $("#historialPT").fadeIn();
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
        });
        $(".btnWallpaper").on("click", function(e){
            $("#dashboardPT").fadeOut();
            $("#wallpaperdPT").fadeIn();
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
        });
        $(".btnEnvioT").on("click", function(e){
            $("#dashboardPT").fadeOut();
            $("#tarjetasAPT").fadeIn();
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
        });     


        // Volver
        $(".btnVovlverDas").on("click", function(e){
            $("#instruccionesPT").fadeOut();
            $("#catalogoPT").fadeOut();
            $("#historialPT").fadeOut();
            $("#wallpaperdPT").fadeOut();
            $("#tarjetasAPT").fadeOut();
            $("#dashboardPT").fadeIn();
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
        });

        $('#MensajeAmigoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
          var element = $(e.relatedTarget);
          var data = element.data("tarjeta");
          $("#imagenenviar").html('<img src="'+data+'" style="width: 100%;"/>');
          $("#imangen_amigo").val(data);
        });  

        //Puntos
        EnergyPointBS();
        var diass = '<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$fecha -1 day"));  ?>';
        Historial(diass);

        $('#comodines').on('show.bs.modal   ', function (e) {
          comodines();
        });

        $("#comodin_nombre_apellido").keyup(function(e){
            $("#comodin_id").val("");
            $("#comodin_nombre_apellido").val("");
        });

        comprobarEliminados();
    });

    jQuery.fn.reset = function () {
      $(this).each (function() { this.reset(); });
    }

    function registros(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"function/puntosDAO.function.php",
            dataType:"JSON",
            data:formRegistro.serialize()+"&tipo=registro_reto",
            success: function(data){
                if(data.state == "ok"){
                    var centro = formRegistro.find("select[name='registro_centro']").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"function/puntosDAO.function.php",
                        dataType:"JSON",
                        data:"&tipo=obtenercentro&centros_id="+centro,
                        success: function(data){
                            if(data.state == "ok"){
                                $.each(data.result, function(i, item){  
                                    formRegistro.reset();           
                                    $("#inicio_session").fadeIn();
                                    $("#registro").fadeOut();           
                                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['2']; ?>");
                                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['8']; ?>"+item.centros_nombre);
                                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();                                     
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });                                                     
                }else if(data.state == "email"){
                    formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_email']").css('color', '#ff0000');   
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['3']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['13']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();                 
                }else if(data.state == "username"){
                    formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_username']").css('color', '#ff0000');
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['3']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['14']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();                 
                }else{
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['3']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['10']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();                     
                }
            },
            beforeSend: function(data){
                if(formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_nombre']").val() == ""){
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();
                    return false;
                }else if(formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_apellido']").val() == ""){
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['1']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();                 
                    return false;
                }else if(formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_telefono']").val() == ""){
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['2']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();  
                    return false;           
                }else if(formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_email']").val() == ""){
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['3']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal(); 
                    return false;
                }else if(formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_username']").val() == ""){
                    formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_username']").css('color', '#444444');
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['4']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();  
                    return false;
                }else if(formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_password']").val() == ""){
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['5']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();  
                    return false;
                }else if(formRegistro.find("select[name='registro_pais']").val() == "null"){
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['11']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();  
                    return false;
                }else if(formRegistro.find("select[name='registro_centro']").val() == "null"){
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['12']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();  
                    return false;
                }else if(formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_email']").val().indexOf('@', 0) == -1 || 
                    formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_email']").val().indexOf('.', 0) == -1){
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['6']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();
                    formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_email']").css('color', '#ff0000');   
                    return false;
                }else{
                    formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_email']").css('color', '#444444');   
                    formRegistro.find("input[name='registro_username']").css('color', '#444444');   
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['4']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['12']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal({
                        keyboard: false,
                        backdrop: 'static'
                    });
                }                                                                                                   
            }
        });         
    }

    function login_reto(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"function/puntosDAO.function.php",
            dataType:"JSON",
            data:formLoginReto.serialize()+"&tipo=login_reto",
            success: function(data){
                if(data.state == "ok"){
                    var dashboard = "dashboard.php";
                    document.location.href=dashboard;                                                   
                }else{
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['3']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['15']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();                     
                }
            },
            beforeSend: function(data){
                if(formLoginReto.find("input[name='email']").val() == ""){
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['17']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();
                    return false;
                }else if(formLoginReto.find("input[name='password']").val() == ""){
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['0']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['17']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal();                 
                    return false;
                }else{
                    $("#modales_mensajes_title").text("<?php echo $modales_titulo['4']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes_contenido").text("<?php echo $modales_contenido['16']; ?>");
                    $("#modales_mensajes").modal({
                        keyboard: false,
                        backdrop: 'static'
                    });
                }                                                                                                   
            }
        });         
    }
```

Este es el archivo de conexión que pide puntosDAOclass.php

```
<?php 
class DBManager{
    public function con(){
            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            mysqli_select_db("agarciac_evolution");
            mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8'");
            if(!$conexion){
                return FALSE;

            }else{
                return $conexion;
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Este es puntosDAO.class.php

```
<?php 
/* CONEXION BASE DE DATOS */
include_once("conexion.class.php");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');
class puntosDAO{
    private $r;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->r = array(); 
    }       
    public function verificar_registro_email($registro_email){
        $con = DBManager::con();
        $q = "SELECT * FROM reto_registro WHERE registro_email = '".$registro_email."' ";
        $rpta = mysqli_query($q, $con);
        mysqli_close($con);
        while($file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rpta)){
            $this->r[]=$file;
        }
        return $this->r;
    }  
    public function comprobarEliminados($registro_id){
        $con = DBManager::con();
        $q = "SELECT * FROM reto_registro WHERE registro_id = '".$registro_id."' AND registro_eliminado = '1' ";
        $rpta = mysqli_query($q, $con);
        mysqli_close($con);
        while($file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rpta)){
            $this->r[]=$file;
        }
        return $this->r;
    }   
    public function updatePassword($registro_id, $registro_password){
        $con = DBManager::con();
        $registro_password = md5($registro_password); 
        $q = "UPDATE reto_registro SET registro_password = '".$registro_password."' WHERE registro_id = '".$registro_id."' ";
        $rpta = mysqli_query($q, $con);
        mysqli_close($con);
        if($rpta==1){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }   
    }   
    public function verificar_registro_username($registro_username){
        $con = DBManager::con();
        $q = "SELECT * FROM reto_registro WHERE registro_username = '".$registro_username."' ";
        $rpta = mysqli_query($q, $con);
        mysqli_close($con);
        while($file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rpta)){
            $this->r[]=$file;
        }
        return $this->r;
    }   
    public function registro_reto($registro_nombre, $registro_apellido, $registro_telefono, $registro_email, $registro_username, $registro_password, $registro_centro, $registro_estatus){ 
        $con = DBManager::con();
        $registro_password = md5($registro_password);
        $q = "INSERT INTO reto_registro(registro_nombre, registro_apellido, registro_telefono, registro_email, registro_username, registro_password, registro_centro, registro_estatus) VALUES ('".$registro_nombre."', '".$registro_apellido."', '".$registro_telefono."', '".$registro_email."', '".$registro_username."', '".$registro_password."', '".$registro_centro."', '".$registro_estatus."')";
        $rpta = mysqli_query($q, $con);
        mysqli_close($con);
        if($rpta==1){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }   
    }     
    public function cargar_paises(){
        $con = DBManager::con();
        $q = "SELECT * FROM sm_paises";
        $rpta = mysqli_query($q, $con);
        mysqli_close($con);
        while($file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rpta)){
            $this->r[]= array_map('utf8_encode', $file);
        }
        return $this->r;
    }  
    public function cargar_centros($paises_id){
        $con = DBManager::con();
        $q = "SELECT * FROM sm_centros WHERE paises_id = '".$paises_id."' ORDER BY centros_nombre";
        $rpta = mysqli_query($q, $con);
        mysqli_close($con);
        while($file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rpta)){
            $this->r[]= array_map('utf8_encode', $file);
        }
        return $this->r;
    }  
    public function obtenercentro($centros_id){
        $con = DBManager::con();
        $q = "SELECT * FROM sm_centros WHERE centros_id = '".$centros_id."' ";
        $rpta = mysqli_query($q, $con);
        mysqli_close($con);
        while($file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rpta)){
            $this->r[]= array_map('utf8_encode', $file);
        }
        return $this->r;
    }
```

Comment: Deberías de publicar el error que te dá en consola, así podremos saber si es un problema de librerias `javascript` o si es el servidor.

Comment: No he logrado hacer que me muestren cosas en consola, el unico error que me da es "login_reto is not defined"

Comment: Sigo con el mismo error, las funciones no parecen reaccionar, el error que da es que no estan definidas

Comment: Generalmente esto pasa por que no está imprimiendo bien los `scripts.php`. La solución que tienes es mirar el codigo fuente de la pagina, y donde debería de pegar `scripts.php` , copialo y actualiza tu pregunta, de esta manera sabremos cual es el verdadero problema.